# Login Through Instagram App instead of Safari

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, safari, instagram-api

I need to integrate Instagram login in my app. So I am redirecting to safari in my application to login in Instagram. but what i have to do is, if user have Insta app installed and he/she is already logged in there then the login screen should not come he can directly go to authentication approval.

my Login code is,

```
- (NSURLRequest *) loginRequest {

    NSString * urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=%@&redirect_uri=%@&response_type=token", self.clientID, self.redirectURI];

    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    return [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
}
```

I went through too many questions here but didn't got the answer. its not feasible or what , i am totally confused .

Comment: its is not possible with safari controller in iOS for Instagram login in iOS 9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to instagram official [docs](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/)

There are two types of authentication available

- Client-Side (Implicit) Authentication
- Server-side (Explicit) Flow

Both of which uses a instagram end point to login the user in the web page.

> There is no authentication available through their iOS/Android app